# Can I stop Material-UI SpeedDial from closing when a SpeedDialAction button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, speed-dial

I am wanting to disable the default behaviour of Material-UI's SpeedDial component (https://material-ui.com/api/speed-dial/).

Currently when you click a SpeedDialAction, the parent SpeedDial component will close.

I would like to change the behaviour so that when a SpeedDialAction is clicked the parent SpeedDial component will stay open.

Is there a simple way for me to disable the 'closing' behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: You handle the click event so inside of your handleClick, just remove the part that closes the speed dial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpeedDial` component's open state is controlled via the prop `open`. The default example for the `SpeedDial` has the following `onClick` function on the `SpeedDialAction` component:

```
const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(false);
}
```

`setOpen` sets the `open` state to `false` when an item is clicked, and this state is passed to the `SpeedDial` component causing it to close.

So, just don't set this state in the `onClick`, and your `SpeedDial` will remain open. :)